# PDFsharp/MigraDoc Add background images to pages

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdfsharp, migradoc

**GOAL**

To open an existing PDF file with multiple pages and add background image to all pages. (Optionally the background image of the first page differs from the others)

In my current implementation (I use .NET 6 and PDFsharp btw.) I add the image to each page, which increases the size of the file dependent on the number of pages.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way in PDFsharp/MigraDoc to embed a background image only once into the document and then reference it for each page?

**CODE**

Both PDF document and the image come from a database as byte arrays.

```
public byte[] AddBackgroundImgToDocument(byte[] doc, byte[] imgFirstPage, byte[]? imgOtherPages=null)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(doc);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
    {
        if(i > 0 && imgOtherPages != null && imgOtherPages.Length > 0)
            AddBackgroundImageFromByteArray(pdfDoc.Pages[i], imgOtherPages);
        else
            AddBackgroundImageFromByteArray(pdfDoc.Pages[i], imgFirstPage);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
    using var oms = new MemoryStream();
    pdfDoc.Save(oms);
    ms.Dispose();
    pdfDoc.Dispose();
    return oms.ToArray();
}

public void AddBackgroundImageFromByteArray(PdfPage page, byte[] imgfile)
{
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
    MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgfile);
    ms.Position = 0;
    XImage image = XImage.FromStream(() => ms);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
    ms.Dispose();
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Rewriting the method above according to accepted answer, solved my problem:

```
public void AddBackgroundImageFromByteArray(PdfPage page, byte[] imgfile)
{
    if(!ximageLoaded)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgfile);
        ms.Position = 0;
        backimg = XImage.FromStream(() => ms);
        ms.Dispose();
        ximageLoaded = true;
    }

    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
    gfx.DrawImage(backimg, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
}
```

Comment: @KJ Yes, the images were written the same way starting at x0,y0 and covering the whole pages. As mentioned in the question there are only two different images optionally. Optimization using ghostscript would help, but the problem occurs while embedding the images programmatically during runtime. The memory consumption increases about 30-50 MB for each page.  In case of a document with 10 pages, I observed 500 MB memory usage, which is not really acceptable for a background service. The other problem with GS is, that die output file has to be sent to a REST service.GS would make it more complex

Comment: The output document is not printed on the screen. After adding background image it is sent to a REST service as Base64-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDFsharp and MigraDoc this optimization is done automatically if you use them as intended.

Load the image once with PDFsharp and add it to as many pages as you like, there will be only one copy of the image in the document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question with the code of current implementation. You mean I should create the XImage object from byte-array only once and then call gfx.DrawImage() for each page with the same XImage object?

Comment: Yep, create the XImage only once. You do not use files and you effectively bypass the optimization of PDFsharp.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Creating the XImage only once and reuisng it, did the magick. :)